# How to auto sum dynamic input fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, sum

I'm trying to make an auto sum.

I'm starting with a text input field and a button. Pushing the button ads a new input field. Sum field should get ... the sum.
I have troubles adding the values in javascipt.

Thanks!

```
var counter = 1;
sum.value= number0.value;
function addNumber(divName){          
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='number" + counter + "'>";
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
      sum.value += document.getElementById("number' + counter + '").value;
      nr++;          
 }

...

<div id="field"> Add value: <input type="button" value="add" onClick="addNumber('total');"><br>
<div id="total"><input type="text" name="number0"></div>

<input type="text" name="sum" id="sum">
```

Comment: Values will always come back as strings so you will need to parseInt($(input).value) before adding. It appears you're using .= instead of += in your sum logic. That will fail, I think thats only for concatenation in PHP..

Comment: @Brant   You are right with "+=". How should the parseInt($(input).value) be in my case, because i think i get stuck in quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
var counter = 1;

function addNumber(divName){    
  var sum = document.getElementById('sum');
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='number" + counter + "'>";
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  sum.value = getSum(counter);
  counter++;              
 }

 function getSum(numberOfDivs) {
   var sum = 0;
   for (var i=0 ; i<numberOfDivs; i++) {
     sum += parseInt(document.getElementsByName('number' + i)[0].value);
   }
   return sum;
 }
```

Check this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/5UE6YyDWmaHq5ZvVY542

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: Explanation of the code is after the snippet.

Here's a rewrite of your code that accounts for `NaN` results and updates as the fields are changed (not only when the "Add" button is clicked). It also dynamically generates the first field, too. ;)

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var counter = 0, sum = document.getElementById('sum');
    document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
        counter += addNumber(counter, sum);
    });
    counter += addNumber(counter, sum);
};

function addNumber(counter, sum) {
    calculateSum(sum);
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="number' + counter + '" class="number" />';
    newdiv.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        calculateSum(sum);
    });
    sum.parentNode.insertBefore(newdiv, sum);
    return 1;
}

function calculateSum(sum) {
    sum.value = 0;
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('number');
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        sum.value = (isNaN(parseInt(sum.value)) ? 0 : parseInt(sum.value)) + (isNaN(parseInt(divs[i].value)) ? 0 : parseInt(divs[i].value));
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
    Add value: <input type="button" value="add" id="add" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" />
</div>
```

It's pure JavaScript and is set-up to run without needing to call the functions from within the HTML.

Simply put, I separated the `addNumber()` into two functions. One to add a new field and the other to determine the total sum.

The `addNumber()` adds a new number field, applies an `EventListener` to the added fields to execute the `calculatSum()` whenever the browser recognizes a `keyup` event, and returns a value of `1` which is then added to the `counter` variable.

The `calculateSum()` zeros the sum and recalculates using the `.number` I added to the generated `input` fields. It is `NaN`-safe. Basically, this means the values that are ran through `parseInt()` are then checked that they are numbers. If `parseInt()` fails, it reports the value as `Not a Number`, or `NaN`. The function forces it to report a value of `0` instead of `NaN`.

To top it off, the script starts by defining the `counter` variable as `0`, adding an `EventListener` for whenever the "Add" button gets clicked, and executes the `addNumber()` to place the first number field.